# move last three characters of column to a new column

Tags: mysql

I have a column ( cases ) that contains 14 characters xxxxxxxxxx-xxx
I need to remove the "-" and move the last three characters to column ( subcase )

is there a easy way to do this as there are 1000's of entries

Answer (score 2):

Create your new column, then do something like:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET subcase = RIGHT(cases,3)
   ,cases = LEFT(cases,10)
```

Comment: I would add `WHERE cases LIKE '__________-___'`, just to be 100% certain that your data adheres to the stated format. Not necessary if the OP is correct that all the data is in that format - but, if it isn't, this would make a real mess of things. With the confirmation check, you're even OK if you ran the command twice by mistake....

Comment: @RDFozz That's a good suggestion. You could also break it into two separate updates, one for `subcase` and one for `case`, and only run the second once you've verified the first. Another way to verify things will work how you expect is to do something like: `SELECT cases, LEFT(cases,10), RIGHT(cases,10) FROM mytable` to make sure your formulas are right before running the `UPDATES`.

Answer (score 1):

Run an ALTER TABLE to add the new column and then

```
UPDATE mytable
SET newcolumn = SUBSTRING_INDEX(cases, '-', -1), -- everything after the dash
        cases = SUBSTRING_INDEX(cases, '-', 1)   -- everything before the dash
```

Of course test before you run this against your production data.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an idea to NOT update the original table 'in situ', but rather SELECTing from it, and creating a new table.  Principle: retain a copy of the old table, until we have checked that the data have been modified successfully.  E.g. if we have some test data, in a table called olddata:

```
-- generate some test data
create table letters ( ltr char(1) ) ;

insert into letters values
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('f'),('g'),('h'),('i'),
('j'),('k'),('l'),('m'),('n'),('o'),('p'),('q'),('r'),
('s'),('t'),('u'),('v'),('w'),('x'),('y'),('z');

-- table with rows containing values in the format xxxxxxxxxx-xxx
create table olddata as
select 
  concat (
    left( md5(concat(t1.ltr, t2.ltr, t3.ltr)) , 10 )
    , '-'
    , upper( right( md5(concat(t1.ltr, t2.ltr, t3.ltr)) , 3 ) )
  ) oldcolumn
from letters t1, letters t2, letters t3 ;

mysql> select count(*) from olddata;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    17576 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from olddata limit 10;
+----------------+
| oldcolumn      |
+----------------+
| 47bce5c74f-808 |
| 8cdcda79a8-AC0 |
| f931822fed-C3D |
| afa939adf5-54A |
| fdb93d315c-793 |
| ddbceb9078-CF2 |
| 1fa591128e-2B3 |
| 72d2037171-B55 |
| b8d112988a-10B |
| cebca6cd3c-E22 |
+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Create a new table by selecting from the old table*. (No need to modify/drop the old table as yet).

```
create table newdata as
select 
  left(oldcolumn , 10) leftcol
, right(oldcolumn, 3) rightcol
from olddata;
```

*Check that everything went to plan*, (only then drop the old table - if necessary).

```
mysql> select * from newdata limit 10;
+------------+----------+
| leftcol    | rightcol |
+------------+----------+
| 47bce5c74f | 808      |
| 8cdcda79a8 | AC0      |
| f931822fed | C3D      |
| afa939adf5 | 54A      |
| fdb93d315c | 793      |
| ddbceb9078 | CF2      |
| 1fa591128e | 2B3      |
| 72d2037171 | B55      |
| b8d112988a | 10B      |
| cebca6cd3c | E22      |
+------------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Queries for checking every single row ...

```
select count(*) rows_transferred
from olddata O, newdata N
where left(O.oldcolumn, 10) = N.leftcol
  and right(O.oldcolumn, 3) = N.rightcol
; 

+------------------+
| rows_transferred |
+------------------+
|            17576 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (27.81 sec)

-- or even
select 
  case 
    when O.oldrows - N.rows_transferred = 0 then 'No rows missed!'
    else 'Something went wrong.'
  end "transfer to new table"
from 
  ( select count(*) oldrows from olddata ) O
, ( select count(*) rows_transferred
    from olddata O, newdata N
    where left(O.oldcolumn, 10) = N.leftcol
      and right(O.oldcolumn, 3) = N.rightcol
   ) N
;
```